# I call Controller and view through route first time but it show error like this

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, backend

home.php  //controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class home extends Controller
{
    
   public function index($home)
    {
        return view('home',['home'=>$home]);

    }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('home/{home}',[home::class,'index']);
```

home.blade.php

```
  {{home}}
```

ErrorException

> Use of undefined constant home - assumed 'home' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: C:\Users\RASHEED1612E\project\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Comment: did you define home class?

Comment: yes i define it

Comment: public function index($home)
    {
        return view('home',['home'=>$home]);

    }

Comment: <h1>  {{home}}</h1>

Comment: Route::get('home/{home}',[home::class,'index']);

Comment: Missing a `$` in your blade. `{{home}}` should be `{{$home}}`. [Displaying Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call 'home' directly in blade file.
You should replace
`'home.blade.php' {{home}}`
into
 `'home.blade.php' {{$home}}`
Try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a variable in laravel that's how you do it:

```
<h1>{{ $home }}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your home.blade.php change `{{home}}` to `{{$home}}` and it will work.

Comment: Please upvote the answer if this worked. Thanks!

Comment: We usually don't answer questions caused by a typo, we vote to close the question